# how can i add email in one by one using read/write in php

Tags: php

how can i add email in one by one using read/write in php

Am getting the following output and create one folder called "update" update folder contain user entered one email is stored and user enter another email id already existing email id replaced to new email id why?

I need one by one email id called

```
apap@gmail.com
asadsd@gmail.com
```

here are my code please review

```
<form action="demo.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="textEmail">
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Demo.php file are

```
<?php

    // Open the text file
    $f = fopen("update.txt", "w");

    // Write text


$text = strtr(" ",'&nbsp;', $_POST['textEmail']);

    fwrite($f,$text);
    //fwrite($f,$text); 
    // Close the text file
    fclose($f);

    // Open file for reading, and read the line
    $f = fopen("update.txt", "r");

    // Read text
    echo fgets($f); 
    fclose($f);

    ?>
```

Comment: there is any error you are encounter now ?

Comment: No, but geeting the output but replacing existing one in the update.txt for example dedde@gmail.com replace to second time enter email id ddd@gmail.com

Comment: You need to have a new line to each of the email address when write.

Comment: I'm not getting if you want the file to only contain one email (that gets overwritten) or one email per row (append to the existing file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your file as append mode so that you not need to open the file twice, for writing in the file, for you one email per line you need to use the `\n` after each email. For reading use the while loop to read end of the file and use fgets to make sure it reads the whole line at a time.

```
$myfile = fopen("update.txt", "a+");

$txt = $_POST['textEmail']."\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
while(!feof($myfile)) {
  echo fgets($myfile) . "<br/>";
}
fclose($myfile);
```

Documentation: [php_file_create](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp) and [php_file_open](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp)

Comment: Shouldn't be `a+`? `a` = writing only, `a+` = reading & writing

Comment: This is a more complete answer

Answer (score 4):

Open the file in append mode instead of write mode
replace **"w"** with **"a"**

```
$f = fopen("update.txt", "a");
```

From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

> **'w'**   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
>
> **'a'**   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it...

Comment: @White this is the answer should be

Comment: How this is gonna be the answer?

Comment: the context a(append) are write at end of the file everytime when new email address added into the file compare w -> (Write only. Opens and clears the contents of file @RivnatNasah

Comment: Only the append mode is not the issue of this question.

Comment: @RivnatNasah oh ok! im overlooked the question

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure on what you are trying to achieve but I will clarify the difference between file write and file append.

Writing to a file when opened in 'w' mode writes from the current file pointer position which when open in 'w' mode is the very beginning of the file, to change this position in this mode use the `fseek()` method.

Writing to a file when opened in 'a' mode (append mode) will set the file pointer to the last location in the file and in php specifically will always when `fwrite()` is called will write to the end of the file.

**Append File Example**

Contents of update.txt before write:

```
sometext
sometext2
```

**Code that writes to file**

```
$f = fopen('update.txt', 'w');

//Description of 'a' mode from php manual
//Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file.
//If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. In this mode,
//fseek() has no effect, writes are always appended.

fwrite($f, "somevalue" . "\n");
fclose($f);
```

**Results In an update.txt with contents:**

```
sometext
sometext2
somevalue
```

Php doc on functions used in this example:

[fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)
[fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($_POST['textEmail'] != '') {
    $text = str_replace(" ", '&nbsp;', $_POST['textEmail']);
    $pattern = '/([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/';
    preg_match_all($pattern,file_get_contents("update.txt"), $matches);
    $emails = $matches[0];   // get Array of all email in file 
    if (!in_array($text, $emails)) {     // echck for existing email 
        file_put_contents("update.txt", PHP_EOL.$_POST['textEmail'], FILE_APPEND);
    }else{
        echo 'Email address alerady exist';
    }
   echo  $f = file_get_contents("update.txt");
}
?>
```

Would you please try this for demo.php ?